# AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'type'

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I am trying to build a program that will retrieve the scores of the NHL's season through the use of yahoo's RSS feed.

I am not an experienced programmer, so some things haven't quite gotten into my head just yet. However, here is my code so far:

---

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

YAHOO_NHL_URL = 'http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/rss'

def retrievalyahoo():
    nhl_site = urlopen('http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/rss')
    tree = ET.parse(urlopen(nhl_site))

retrievalyahoo()
```

---

The title above states the error I get after I test the aforementioned code.

EDIT: Okay, after the fix, the traceback error comes as this, to which I am puzzled:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Nathaniel's Folder/Website Scores.py", line 12, in <module>
    retrievalyahoo()
  File "C:/Nathaniel's Folder/Website Scores.py", line 10, in retrievalyahoo
    tree = ET.parse(nhl_site)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1242, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1730, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse(source)
  File "<string>", line None
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 17, column 291
```

Comment: In the future, don't just give us the error text, give the whole traceback. That will tell us which line the error happened on, and possibly additional information that's useful.

Comment: Use python-3.x tag if you are running your programs using python 3

Comment: Also, in Python 3.3 or later, don't use `cElementTree`. It is still present as an alias to `ElementTree`, but only as a workaround to help `2to3` and for backward compatibility to earlier 3.x, not as something you should actually use.

Comment: Your new problem is a new problem, so you should create a new question for it, not try to follow up on this question. Otherwise, the answers and comments will turn into a huge mess. (However, from a quick glance, despite being called `rss`, the page is actually HTML, not RSS or any other XML format, so you're probably going to want to use an HTML parser on it. The error message is telling you that it's not valid XML, which isn't surprising if it's not XML.)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're trying to call `urlopen` on the result of `urlopen`.

Just call it once, like this:

```
nhl_site = urlopen('http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/rss')
tree = ET.parse(nhl_site)
```

The error message probably could be nicer. If you look at the docs for [`urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen):

> Open the URL *url*, which can be either a string or a `Request` object.

Clearly the `http.client.HTTPResponse` object that it returns is neither a string nor a `Request` object. What's happened here is that `urlopen` sees that it's not a string, and therefore assumes it's a `Request`, and starts trying to access methods and attributes that `Request` objects have. This kind of design is generally a good thing, because it lets you pass things that act just like a `Request` and they'll just work… but it does mean that if you pass something that *doesn't* act like a `Request`, the error message can be mystifying.